# Apply padding, style to number of company pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The number of company pages needs some padding and styling.  It doesn't look like the number of jobs in the **search jobs** tab.  It has a different style and it doesn't I believe have enough padding around it to separate it out from the first result.

Whatever is done in **search jobs** can this be applied to **search companies** in terms of this label?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Fix is building out now.